# How do I enable logging for HttpClient in a .NET Core console app?

Tags: .net-core, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

**.NET Core 2.2**

I have a basic CLI created with `dotnet new console`. It uses `HttpClient` to make web requests. How can I see trace or logging information about these requests?

Data like this:
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging

In the .NET Framework, you could turn on System Tracing: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

Comment: You linked to the answer itself. The logging infrastructure is the same in .NET Core, whether it's ASP.NET Core or a console application. The thing you need to check is how to enable logging in a console application

Comment: If you're really lazy you can use [the generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to configure DI, logging, configuration etc in a single call similar to what ASP.NET Core does. Calling `Run` or `RunAsync` on the host will start any hosted services registered, which means you'll have to implement your own code inside hosted services

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. That Generic Host example got me going. Also needed to create the HttpClient via IHttpClientFactory. Seeing log output now!

Answer (score 2):

In your appsettings.json file there will be an object which looks similar to the following:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

Increase the log level to Information and run your application again. Once you have done that, take a look at this page in the [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/) for how to enable logging to file or the terminal.

Comment: In addition to Jamie's solution here, I found that HttpClient calls would not be logged unless the *ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT* environment variable was set to *Development* (for example in appsettings.json)

Comment: downvoted, becode this works for ASP.NET Core, not console app